# Replace keyboard events with mobile swipes

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

I made a javascript game and I was wondering how can I adapt it so I can play this game on mobile too.

All I want is to replace arrow keys events with mobile swipes;

My moving function looks like this:

```
    switch (e.keyCode) {

            case 37:
                    //do this
            case 38:
                    //do this
            case 39:
                    //do this
            case 40:
                    //do this
        }
```

How can I **add another switch case for swipe down (from a mobile device)** is it hard to do?

PS preferably without jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this by `addEventListener('touchstart',handleTouchStart)` and `addEventListener('touchmove',handleTouchMove)` and write the `handleTouchStart` & `handleTouch` functions and compare the touch position to the previous position each time to get the direction.

Or just use hammerjs library => https://hammerjs.github.io/